# Export to excel from PHP, mysql (mutiple query in page),code not functioning correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, export-to-excel, phpexcel

Hi below is the code I used to export data from php page to excel file.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","testp");
mysql_select_db("dbone1", $con);

$ts = date("d/m/y : H:i:s", time()) ;

$datav=$_GET["datav"];
$pathogen=$_GET["pathogen"];
$topic1 = $_GET['toc1'];
$testvar1 = unserialize(rawurldecode($_GET['ind1']));
$subindg1 = $_GET['isg1'];
$topic2 = $_GET['toc2'];
$testvar2 = unserialize(rawurldecode($_GET['ind2']));
$subindg2 = $_GET['isg2'];
$topic3 = $_GET['toc3'];
$testvar3 = unserialize(rawurldecode($_GET['ind3']));
$subindg3 = $_GET['isg3'];
$topic4 = $_GET['toc4'];
$testvar4 = unserialize(rawurldecode($_GET['ind4']));
$subindg4 = $_GET['isg4'];
$topic5 = $_GET['toc5'];
$testvar5 = unserialize(rawurldecode($_GET['ind5']));
$subindg5 = $_GET['isg5'];
$testvar6 = unserialize(rawurldecode($_GET['cnty']));

function addWrapper (&$value, $key, $wrapper) {
$value = $wrapper.$value.$wrapper;
//no return, passed by reference
}

if(empty($testvar6))
{
}
else
{
array_walk($testvar6, 'addWrapper', "");
$sql_cntys = implode("','", $testvar6);
//echo $sql_cntys;
}

$num1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mtable WHERE DataVersionDate='$datav' && Pathogen='$pathogen' && Topic='$topic1' && Indicator='$ind1' && IndicatorSubGroup='$subindg1' && (Country IN ('$sql_cntys') OR  Location_Who IN ('$sql_cntys')) ");
$num2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mtable WHERE DataVersionDate='$datav' && Pathogen='$pathogen' && Topic='$topic2' && Indicator='$ind2' && IndicatorSubGroup='$subindg2' && (Country IN ('$sql_cntys') OR  Location_Who IN ('$sql_cntys')) ");
$num3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mtable WHERE DataVersionDate='$datav' && Pathogen='$pathogen' && Topic='$topic3' && Indicator='$ind3' && IndicatorSubGroup='$subindg3' && (Country IN ('$sql_cntys') OR  Location_Who IN ('$sql_cntys')) ");
$num4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mtable WHERE DataVersionDate='$datav' && Pathogen='$pathogen' && Topic='$topic4' && Indicator='$ind4' && IndicatorSubGroup='$subindg4' && (Country IN ('$sql_cntys') OR  Location_Who IN ('$sql_cntys')) ");
$num5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mtable WHERE DataVersionDate='$datav' && Pathogen='$pathogen' && Topic='$topic5' && Indicator='$ind5' && IndicatorSubGroup='$subindg5' && (Country IN ('$sql_cntys') OR  Location_Who IN ('$sql_cntys')) ");

$data = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($num1))
{
    $c = $row['Country'];
    if (!isset($data[$c]))
    {
        $data[$c] = array('Country' => $c);
    }
    $data[$c]['MidEstimate1'] = $row['MidEstimate'];
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($num2))
{
    $c = $row['Country'];
    if (!isset($data[$c]))
    {
        $data[$c] = array('Country' => $c);
    }
    $data[$c]['MidEstimate2'] = $row['MidEstimate'];
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($num3))
{
    $c = $row['Country'];
    if (!isset($data[$c]))
    {
        $data[$c] = array('Country' => $c);
    }
    $data[$c]['MidEstimate3'] = $row['MidEstimate'];
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($num4))
{
    $c = $row['Country'];
    if (!isset($data[$c]))
    {
        $data[$c] = array('Country' => $c);
    }
    $data[$c]['MidEstimate4'] = $row['MidEstimate'];
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($num5))
{
    $c = $row['Country'];
    if (!isset($data[$c]))
    {
        $data[$c] = array('Country' => $c);
    }
    $data[$c]['MidEstimate5'] = $row['MidEstimate'];
}

require_once '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Country')
            ->setCellValue('B1', 'MidEstimate1')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'MidEstimate2')
            ->setCellValue('D1', 'MidEstimate3')
            ->setCellValue('E1', 'MidEstimate4')
            ->setCellValue('F1', 'MidEstimate5');

$r=2;

$i = 0;

foreach ($data as $row)
{
    ($i % 5);

            $a="A".$r;
        $b="B".$r;
        $c="C".$r;
        $d="D".$r;
        $e="E".$r;
        $f="F".$r;

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue($a, $row['Country'])
                ->setCellValue($b, $row['MidEstimate1'])
                ->setCellValue($c, $row['MidEstimate2'])
                ->setCellValue($d, $row['MidEstimate3'])
                ->setCellValue($e, $row['MidEstimate4'])
                ->setCellValue($f, $row['MidEstimate5']);

        $r++;

}



$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$ts.xls");
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

while export, there is only header(column titles) and no data ? please help me to correct this code.

Comment: you could form a resultant array from all of your queries and then work under Excel code to produce excel file.

Comment: You could just collapse all those separate queries into a single query with slightly more complex `WHERE` clause.

Comment: hi can anyone can give a start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just dropped your complete code here, so I assume you don't have the faintest idea of where it's failing. Well, that's the most basic troubleshooting technique: isolating the part of the code that doesn't work as expected. In your case, the interesting points are:

## 1. SQL queries

First, while debugging you have to print the SQL code on screen and run it in your favourite MySQL client to make sure that it returns the data you want.

Second, you always have to check the return value of [mysql_query()](http://php.net/mysql_query) and take actions if they fail (for instance, log the [mysql_error()](http://php.net/mysql_error) and abort the script).

## 2. Variables

Use [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) to inspect your variables and make sure they have the information you think they have.

## 3. PHPExcel

Don't even try to create an Excel spreadsheet until you've populated `$data` successfully.

---

**Edit:** If you followed my advice and printed your SQL query:

```
var_dump(
    "SELECT * FROM mtable WHERE DataVersionDate='$datav' && Pathogen='$pathogen' && Topic='$topic1' && Indicator='$ind1' && IndicatorSubGroup='$subindg1' && (Country IN ('$sql_cntys') OR  Location_Who IN ('$sql_cntys')) "
);
```

You would already know whether `$datav` has the right value or not. If the value is not correct, then you know the issue is here:

```
$datav=$_GET["datav"];
```

Otherwise, you can forget about the URL. And so on.

Comment: Hi,
I checked my query with mysql_eroor and its ok, but $data is showing empty ! I am transferring few variables from one page to this excel code using url. I am checking where I failed ? thanx for the reply.

Comment: URL? Your code has no reference to `$_GET` :-? ... I think you haven't got the point: don't troubleshoot your complete code base at a time, divide it into pieces!

Comment: hi "Álvaro G. Vicario" the complete code is here now. I already checked the variable are geting values.. but I am checking why $data is getting empty !.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.... "Álvaro G. Vicario". Sometimes I fail due to the hurry!. Well $data is empty due to the wrong variable placed in sql queries. Once its loaded its working and lot of thanx for ur advice in rules to be followed while checking the code. I am a novice user in php. I work in domino, its got a debuger which its easy to find the code working ! thank you once again for the help.